# MySQL ALTER TABLE hangs

Tags: mysql

I know this question was asked several times already but my problem is happening with a table I've just created. It has only 10 columns and only 1 row in it.

So unlike the usual hanging problem this is not the case of a large table with a lot of data. And yet it hangs.

This is the SQL I'm running:

```
ALTER TABLE `db`.`Search` 
ADD COLUMN `useremail` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `id`;
```

Simple enough and yet it hangs (50 minutes and counting.) I tried quitting `Workbench` and `Eclipse` and deleting all `java` processes and the one `mysqld` process. But no luck.

I'm running on a `Mac OSX El Capitain`. How do I add this column to my table?

Comment: could you please run this query `Show full processlist` and tell me if there's any query like `ALTER TABLE `db`.`Search` 
ADD COLUMN `useremail` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL COMMENT '' AFTER `id`;` running ?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu Yes there is. The "state" is "Waiting for table metadata lock."

Comment: What's the PID of that process? how many records are there in the table?

Comment: The ID is 2134 and there is only one record in the table.

Comment: ok then kill the process using this command `kill 2134`. Then retry and let me know what happened this time.

Comment: Same thing, it hangs. I aborted it, run Show full processlist and the alter table process isn't there. But there is another process with the same pid (2134) that's waiting for a Drop Table query (I run it before.) When I do a kill 2134 now, it says "Unknown thread id" although the process is there.

Comment: could you please restart your MySQL server and repeat the process?

Comment: I can't right now, other people are using it in different locations. I guess I'll try later.

Comment: OK after restart the hang disappeared. But why did it happen in the first place?

Comment: May be the number of processes running at that moment was too high. what was the number of rows when you ran `show full processlist` last day?

Comment: Still a handful of rows. This is a development db.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I got to this question by searching "mysql alter table hanging" and think the answer (in the comments) should be documented.

If you're running a MySQL command (in this case to add a column) and it is unexpectedly hanging, e.g. not due to the size of the data in the table, then check the other processes running against the database. I left the query running, connected to the server with another client, and typed

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

My query was hanging, and this message was in the `state` column:

```
Waiting for table metadata lock
```

I noticed I had several zombie connections from my machine, killed them (`KILL xxx` where `xxx` is the number in the `Id` column), and then the process finished immediately.

Comment: Just to add... `kill` command was run inside MySQL terminal, not needed to close it. Thanks!

Comment: Why would zombie connections do this? Do connections not actively even doing anything hold the table metadata lock for some reason? [_proceeds to RTFM_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locking.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Galera Cluster (MariaDB) of a production srver, the freeze was due to an alter table add column with a default value, I could see withing `SHOW PROCESSLIST` 
I shut down the servers to force kill the process, but I had much work to put the cluster on again.

It happened the second time, **all I did is waited for the query to finish** it took about 20 minutes because it had to deal with a 1.5M lines table. then the tables lock is open.