# MySQL "Waiting for table metadata lock" hangs on 1 particular table

Tags: mysql, process, blocking

I'm trying to add a column to a specific table. Every time I run the migration up or down a SLEEP command pops up and blocks everything. Much like many other people who have run into this problem, I kill the blocking process and everything works as expected.

Ex:[MySql alter table hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293625/mysql-alter-table-hangs)

I've tried running the migration against a different table and have no issues. Seems to be something specific with this particular table.

Where or what should I be looking for? Why would this issue occur so consistently?

Thanks.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host            | db     | Command | Time | State                           | Info                                         |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 351 | root | localhost:54691 | database | Sleep   |   25 |                                 | NULL                                         |
| 352 | root | localhost:54692 | NULL     | Sleep   |   54 |                                 | NULL                                         |
| 377 | root | localhost       | database | Query   |    0 | starting                        | show processlist                             |
| 381 | root | localhost:54858 | database | Query   |    5 | Waiting for table metadata lock | ALTER TABLE company ADD COLUMN active        |
| 382 | root | localhost:54860 | database | Sleep   |    5 |                                 | NULL                                         |
+-----+------+-----------------+--------+---------+------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The offending process in this case was `382`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to many other similar posts say to kill the SLEEP process and then "debug". My problem was related to a circular import issue in Python, not related to MySQL.